# Core Data ordering a subarray NSSet

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to sort an array (vociMenu: NSSet) within an entity, but I get this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

this is my code:
**ENTITY**

```
extension SezioniMenu {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SezioniMenu> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SezioniMenu>(entityName: "SezioniMenu");
    }

    @NSManaged public var sezione: String?
    @NSManaged public var language: Language?
    @NSManaged public var vociMenu: NSSet? <---- /// I MUST ORDER THIS ENTITY

}
```

**QUERY**

```
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SezioniMenu> = SezioniMenu.fetchRequest()
                                fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "vociMenu.tipologia", ascending: true)

        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "language.code = %@", Singleton.sharedInstance.linguaDispositivo)

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    do {
                array = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
   .....
```

How can I order the entity "vociMenu: NSSet"?

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**

I managed to solve my situation in this way. Sort the list directly in the delegate of the TableView in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell : CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
       ///For each section retrieve the list to order
       let list = self.listSezioni?[indexPath.section].vociMenu?.allObjects as! [VociMenu]
       ///I run the sort (sort) of the items
       var listSort = list.sorted(by: { $0.tipologia! < $1.tipologia! })

       cell.labelMenu.text = listSort[indexPath.row].tipologia
}
```

Comment: what is vociMenu.tipologia field's type?

Comment: vociMenu.tipologia  is String

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what is your vociMenu.tipologia field's type, but the problem can be in using keyPathes, instead of just keys. Try to use sortDescriptor, instead, created by

```
public init(key: String?, ascending: Bool, comparator cmptr: @escaping Foundation.Comparator)
```

where you can explicitly provide logic for your comparison. Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Your fetchRequest will not sort the vociMenu NSSet but the result array of SezioniMenu.

To sort a NSSet, you can use

```
func sorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Self.Iterator.Element, Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Self.Iterator.Element]
```

function from NSSet object itself where you can define the predicate to sort the set of object.

In your case, assuming that vociMenu attribute is a VociMenu managed object :

```
let sortedVociMenu = self.vociMenu.sorted {return ($0 as! VociMenu).tipologia < ($1 as! VociMenu).tipologia}
```

should works to sort ascending